# IE9 - links not working with background none or transparent

Tags: background, internet-explorer-9, hyperlink

I have no idea why but in IE 9, when I have links on page using absolute positioning they will not seem to work or appear to sit behind everything else, but if you add a background colour it now works. I actually know the answer to this but I am posting it here to let anyone else who has had this problem know how to sort this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
background: url(./this-not-a-hack.gif) repeat;
```